# Securing Authentication From Mobile Devices

Tags: c#, android, ios, authentication, azure

We have started looking at this tutorial to use the new notifications hub in Windows Azure:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/notification-hubs/notify-users-aspnet/

At one point it specifies a warning stating:

"SECURITY NOTE
The AuthenticationTestHandler class does not provide true authentication. It is used only to mimic basic authentication and return a principle. The user name is required to create Notification Hub registrations. The above implementation is not secure. You must implement a secure authentication mechanism in your production applications and services."

Can anyone suggest a good way to secure this that will work from windows phone, android and iOS.  We can't use the built in authentication such as facebook, google, twitter, etc. as it needs to use our own authentication backend.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

To implement cross platform authentication it's best to use a standard like [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/).

OAuth2 allows you to

- Handle logins in one place on server side.
- Your clients only get as few account informations as needed. It's possible to hide the password from clients (whereas not common in mobile apps). Each client gets it's own unique access token.
- Remove access remotely by revoking access tokens on server side.

For implementation:

- [Apache Oltu](http://oltu.apache.org/index.html) is a Java Framework for OAuth2 authentication (server and client support).
- [Udi wrote a very good tutorial for Android authentication.](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/)